# File is attached but empty after form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, file, cakephp

I am using a jquery plugin to show images immediately after attaching. It works fine. But After form submission file input field  is empty. I am using cakephp 2.6 and code for Form:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
                        <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
                           <?php echo $this->Form->create('Tolet', array(
                            'inputDefaults' => array(
                                'label' => false,
                                'div'   => false                                  
                                ),
                            'id'=> 'fileupload',
                            'class' => 'form-horizontal form_sample_2',
                            'novalidate' =>'novalidate',
                            'type' => 'file'
                            )
                            ); ?>
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-5">
                                        <span class="btn green fileinput-button">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                            <span>
                                                Add Image </span>

                                               <?php 
                                               echo $this->Form->input(
                                            'images.',

                                            array(
                                                'type' => 'file',
                                                'multiple' =>'',
                                                'class' => 'form-control'
                                                )

                                            ); 
                                            ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7">

                                        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped clearfix">
                                            <tbody class="files">
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   


  <div class="form-actions">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-3">

                                         <?php 
                                                                     echo $this->Form->button(
                                                                        'Post', 
                                                                        array('class' => 'btn green', 'type' => 'submit')
                                                                        ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
                        <!-- END FORM-->
                    </div>
```

Request data:

```
Array
(
    [Tolet] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [tolet_type_id] => 
            [tolet_condition_id] => 
            [room_no] => 1
            [bath_no] => 1
            [area] => 
            [name] => 
            [cell] => 
            [email] => 
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 
                            [type] => 
                            [tmp_name] => 
                            [error] => 4
                            [size] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is the live demo: http://demo.jegeachi.com/tolets/add

I am sorry if it is very basic question which should not ask in stackoverflow.

Comment: You get a `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` error. Looks like the naming is wrong.

Comment: thanks Kumar for your reply. What is wrong with this name?